# reverse() on querybuilder get() changes the collection results

Tags: laravel, collections, reverse, laravel-query-builder

I need to get last 10 records of a table ordered by a data, and reverse them.

This is the code before the reverse:

```
$eventi = \App\Model::with('relation_1', 'relation_2')
    ->orderBy('data_ora', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

If I log the results I get this:

```
[{"id":12297,"stato_batteria":null,"data_ora":"2018-05-03 11:40:02" ...
```

The reverse code is:

```
$eventi = \App\Model::with('relation_1', 'relation_2')
    ->orderBy('data_ora', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
    ->reverse();
```

If I log the results I get this:

```
{"9":{"id":1410,"stato_batteria":null,"data_ora":"2018-04-05 14:16:48" ...
```

As you can see the collection is changed and I do not know why.

Comment: What do you mean that the collection has changed? You've called `reverse` which returns a *new* collection with the items in reverse order.

Comment: if the collection is not changed, why the 2 collections, written on the log file, are different?

Comment: Did you expect the two outputs to be the same? If not, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect the 2 collections are the same json object, just reverse. If you see what I get in the log you see you have 2 different objects.

Comment: I can't see enough data to make that assumption, can you post your full logs for those two calls?

Comment: `[{"id":12297,"stato_batteria":null` and `{"9":{"id":1410,"stato_batteria"` are pretty different from the beginning. The first one is a json array, the second one is a json object.

Comment: It still doesn't show the data that I want to see. The reason you're seeing a JSON *object* in the second is likely because `reverse` is preserving keys (which initially were numeric). You're seeing expected behaviour I believe but I need to see more data to be able to comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this to reset the keys:

```php
->reverse()->values();
```

Comment: Finally I got an answer! Thanks! Only ```reverse()``` doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 6):

When you do this:

```
$eventi = \App\Model::with('relation_1', 'relation_2')
    ->orderBy('data_ora', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

You get a `Collection` object, containing those values. The *keys* of the values in the underlying array will be numeric, i.e. `0, 1, 2, ... 9`. Now when you're doing:

```
$eventi = \App\Model::with('relation_1', 'relation_2')
    ->orderBy('data_ora', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
    ->reverse();
```

You're getting the same collection back, in reverse order. The `reverse` method creates a *new* collection, but preserves the keys of the original collection. So in this case you'll be seeing the last item, first and the keys will be `9, 8, 7, ... 0`. In PHP, if your array keys aren't integers, in ascending order starting from `0`, it is assumed to be an associative array. So when you're outputting your collection as JSON you're seeing it represented as an object.

A way to ignore the keys in the collection is to use `values`, so that a *new* collection is created (with ascending numeric keys i.e. `0, 1, 2, ... 9`), only with the values of the initial collection:

```
$eventi = \App\Model::with('relation_1', 'relation_2')
    ->orderBy('data_ora', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
    ->reverse()
    ->values();
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in collection documentation of laravel, when u apply `reverse` method to a collection, the collection order will change.

in ur case here u get ur data collection order by `data_ora` and `desc`,

when u apply `reverse` after get, that means u will reverse the collection to be ordered by `data_ora` but `ASC` not `DESC`.

in other words, the first element of collection will be the last ...

check the laravel documentation here [reverse method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-reverse)

Comment: I wrote what I get if I log the 2 collections, and they are 2 different json objects.